# Invoking Kafka Interactive Queries from inside a Stream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-interactive-queries

I have a particular requirement for invoking an Interactive Query from inside a Stream . This is because I need to create a new Stream which should have data contained inside the State Store. Truncated code below:

```java
tempModifiedDataStream.to(topic.getTransformedTopic(), Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));

GlobalKTable<String, String> myMetricsTable = builder.globalTable(
    topic.getTransformedTopic(),
    Materialized.<String, String, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(
            topic.getTransformedStoreName() /* table/store name */)
        .withKeySerde(Serdes.String()) /* key serde */
        .withValueSerde(Serdes.String()) /* value serde */
);

KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), kStreamsConfigs());

KStream<String, String> tempAggrDataStream = tempModifiedDataStream
    .flatMap((key, value) -> {
        try {
            List<KeyValue<String, String>> result = new ArrayList<>();

            ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, String> keyValueStore =
                streams .store(
                    topic.getTransformedStoreName(),
                    QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());
```

In the last line, To access the State Store I need to have the KafkaStreams object  and the Topology is finalized when I create the KafkaStreams object. The problem with this approach is that the 'tempAggrDataStream' is hence not part of the Topology and that part of the code does not get executed. And I cant move the KafkaStreams definition below as otherwise I can't call the Interactive Query.

I am a bit new to Kafka Streams ; so is this something silly from my side?

Comment: Could you describe more precisely, what would you like to achieve? Why this state store is needed? Maybe `join` is what you need (`tempModifiedDataStream.join(myMetricsTable)`?

Comment: Whenever the Ktable is updated, I need the entire contents of the Ktable to be output to a new Topic. I dont think I can achieve this even if i do a left join of the original Stream with its Ktable.

Comment: I still can't get what your needs are. Do you want to copy content of whole topic when at least one value has change? Is destination topic change after every update?

Comment: My Requirement is rather straight forward. I want to write all Key-Value pairs of a KTable into a topic whenever the contents of the KTable changes.
 
 For example, lets say my KTable currently contains 
 <asia 34>,<europe 66>,<australia 77>
 
 A new update comes as <asia 55> . At  that point I want to write a json such as {"asia":"55","europe":"66","australia":"77"} into a Topic. i.e loop through all entries of the KTable and output the data somewhere

Comment: That is not a good use case for Kafka Streams. Also, if you say "new topic" do you mean a new topic for every update? Or one topic that reused for each update?

Comment: Hi Matthias.. I meant the same topic each time. I have a downstream consumer which requires all the data each time. Also there will only be max 30 unique keys in the KTable , so the entire data set won't be too huge. I will check the solution with the Processor API given by wardziniak but plz let me know if any other ways to achieve this...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve sending all content of the topic content after each data modification, I think you should rather use Processor API.

You could create `org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Transformer` with state store.
For each processing message it will update state store and send all content to downstream.
It is not very efficient, because it will be forwarding for each processing message the whole content of the *topic/state store* (that can be thousands, millions of records).

If you need only *latest* value it is enough to  set your topic `cleanup.policy` to `compact`. And from other site use `KTable`, which give abstraction of Table (Snapshot of stream)

Sample Transformer code for forwarding whole content of state store is as follow. The whole work is done in `transform(String key, String value)` method.

```java
public class SampleTransformer
        implements Transformer<String, String, KeyValue<String, String>> {

    private String stateStoreName;
    private KeyValueStore<String, String> stateStore;
    private ProcessorContext context;

    public SampleTransformer(String stateStoreName) {
        this.stateStoreName = stateStoreName;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        this.context = context;
        stateStore = (KeyValueStore) context.getStateStore(stateStoreName);
    }

    @Override
    public KeyValue<String, String> transform(String key, String value) {
        stateStore.put(key, value);
        stateStore.all().forEachRemaining(keyValue -> context.forward(keyValue.key, keyValue.value));
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }
}
```

More information about Processor APi can be found:

- https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html
- https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html

How to combine Processor API with Stream DSL can be found:

- https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#applying-processors-and-transformers-processor-api-integration

Comment: The stateStore obtained from the context is "sharded" in that it will contain only those keys, which belong to a certain partition or a stream task. If there are 5 input partitions, which a single instance of your streams app is consuming, then there'll be 5 separate SampleTransformation objects, each with 1 partition's worth of keys. So, you'll only be publishing a shard of the state of the world. To access the stateStore with all keys, I think you'll need to look into Interactive Queries.